# How to query for MongoDB Document With duplicate Key?

Tags: mongodb

I am having Mongo Documents with duplicate Key,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576a3b4a2bf2bc22bccb80ec"),
    "Name" : "User1",
    "Name" : "User2"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576a3b4a2bf2bc22bccb80ab"),
    "Name" : "User2",
    "Name" : "User1"
}
```

When I try to query for Name as "User1". I always get one document only. But result should be two documents. Is there any way that I get correct result?

Thanks in advance

Note: I know my design is wrong I am just trying to make it success.

Comment: There are two `Name` fields in one record? How that can be possible? Mongodb won't allow inserting duplicate fields.

Comment: No It will allow, try to insert the same document.

Comment: I tried inserting two fields with same name and different values, from mongo shell. it added only one field. What ever document you have shown in question, you got it by doing find in mongo shell?

Comment: Thanks let me try through the mongo shell

Comment: This is not true you can't have duplicate field name in a document. If you insert a document with a duplicate key, only the last value of the key will be retained.

Comment: What is that you actually trying to achieve? It's totally wrong.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-739 An issue with the Ruby driver demonstrates that MongoDB will happily store a single document with duplicate keys. Most drivers prevent this, but if any of the clients connecting to MongoDB attempt to store a document with duplicate keys, MongoDB will store them. Thus, it is possible to have a single document with duplicate keys, and this question is valid.

Comment: Mongodb explicitly allows duplicate keys. Apparently this is also allowed by JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that according to the docs, it IS possible to have duplicate key names, but depending on the driver you either might not be able to insert or read such data:

> BSON documents may have more than one field with the same name. Most MongoDB interfaces, however, represent MongoDB with a structure (e.g. a hash table) that does not support duplicate field names. If you need to manipulate documents that have more than one field with the same name, see the driver documentation for your driver.

(Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names)

Unfortunately, in order to correct your existing data, you will have to use a driver which can handle duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two fields with same name in a collection in  MongoDB .
When you try to insert a document  with two fields with same key , MongoDB will update with the  latest value rather than creating a separate fields.

**Example :**

```
db.test.insert({'Name':'user1','Name':'user2'})

db.test.insert({'Name':'user2','Name':'user1'})
```

> Will result in inserting 2 documents as shown below

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576a8b4731157693143d0571"), "Name" : "user2" }  
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576a8b5531157693143d0572"), "Name" : "user1" }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and it is possible to have duplicate keys in the same document...I'm looking at one now in fact.

Answer (score -1):

```
db.collection_name.find({"Name" : "User1"})
```

Comment: Please consider elaborating on why this answers the OP's question

Answer (score -3):

For a collection the `ObjectId` in MongoDB are unique because it acts as the primary key for that collection. As per the [MongoDB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) You can never have two documents in the same collection with same `ObjectId`.

But for different collections, there's a possibility of having the same `ObjectID`. And in that case while querying you obviously have to mention the collection name.

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually I need one document with same Key not two document with same ObjectId.