# Can I add two different fields with same names inside a document? This may not be the Logical question but I just want to know if it is possible

Tags: mongodb

I tried below code but it is only inserting first field which is
name :"Swapnil"

```
db.emp.insert ({name:"Swapnil", name:"Aditya"})
```

Comment: Short answer - no, you can't. More detailed answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37969188/13375075).

Answer (score 1):

The [The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-4) specification actually would permit it:

> When the names within an object are not
> unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
> unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair
> only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the
> object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs,
> including duplicates.

The [MongoDB documentation - Field Names](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#field-names) says:

> BSON documents may have more than one field with the same name. Most MongoDB interfaces, however, represent MongoDB with a structure (e.g. a hash table) that does not support duplicate field names. If you need to manipulate documents that have more than one field with the same name, see the driver documentation for your driver.

Short answer: it depends on the driver/application you use, it could be possible - **but clearly it is not recommended**